# Why I am getting this error? : Darryldecode\Cart\Exceptions\InvalidItemException validation.required

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce

In my E-commerce website, I installed darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart to add cart functionality.

When I am adding an item to cart from the product page using add to cart, I am getting this error:- Darryldecode\Cart\Exceptions\InvalidItemException validation.required

This is my first project, please guide me on how I need to resolve this. This project kills me. This much I could complete this project with this community's help. Thanks a lot.

**CartController.php**

```
class CartController extends Controller
{
    
    public function index()
    {
        $cartItems = \Cart::session(auth()->id())->getContent();
        
         return view ('cart',compact(cartItems));
         
     }
    
       
      public function show($id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
       
        return view('cart')->with(compact('product'));
   }
   
       public function destroy($itemId)
    {
        \Cart::session(auth()->id())->getContent();
        return back;
    }

    public function add(Product $product)
    {
        
        // add the product to cart
        \Cart::session(auth()->id())->add(array(
        'id' => $product->id,
        'name' => $product->prod_name,
        'price' => $product->prod_price,
        'quantity' => 1,
        'attributes' => array(),
        'associatedModel' => $product
             ));
         return redirect()->route('cart.index');
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/cart', 'CartController@index')->name('cart.index');
Route::get('/cart/{cartItems}', 'CartController@add')->name('cart.add')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/cart/destroy/{itemId}', 'CartController@add')->name('cart.destroy')->middleware('auth');
```

**cart.blade.php**

```
 @foreach($cartItems as $items)
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-center">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$(this).parent().find('form').submit()" class="btn btn-danger">x</a>
                                        <form action="{{ route('cart.destroy',$items->id) }}" method="post">
                                            @method('DELETE')
                                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                  
                                    <td class="d-none d-md-table-cell">
                                        <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid max-width-100 p-1 border border-color-1" src="{{asset('/storage/admin/'.$items ['image'] ) }}" alt="Image Description"></a>
                                    </td>
                                    
                                    <td data-title="Product">
                                        <a href="#" class="text-gray-90">{{ $items ['name'] }}</a>
                                    </td>
                                   
                                    <td data-title="Price">
                                        <span class="">LKR {{ $items ['price'] }}.00</span>
                                    </td>
                                   
                                    <td data-title="Quantity">
                                        <span class="sr-only">Quantity</span>
                                        <!-- Quantity -->
                                        <div class="border rounded-pill py-1 width-122 w-xl-80 px-3 border-color-1">
                                            <div class="js-quantity row align-items-center">
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <input class="js-result form-control h-auto border-0 rounded p-0 shadow-none" type="text" value="1">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-auto pr-1">
                                                    <a class="js-minus btn btn-icon btn-xs btn-outline-secondary rounded-circle border-0" href="javascript:;">
                                                        <small class="fas fa-minus btn-icon__inner"></small>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <a class="js-plus btn btn-icon btn-xs btn-outline-secondary rounded-circle border-0" href="javascript:;">
                                                        <small class="fas fa-plus btn-icon__inner"></small>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- End Quantity -->
                                    </td>

                                    <td data-title="Total">
                                        <span class=""></span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                           
                                @endforeach
```

**product.blade.php**

```
<div class="d-none d-xl-block prodcut-add-cart">
                                                            <a href="{{route('cart.add',$p->id)}}" class="btn-add-cart btn-primary transition-3d-hover"><i class="ec ec-add-to-cart"></i></a>
                                                            </div>
```

Comment: how did you resolve this same exact exception in your last question?

Comment: Check `public function add(Product $product) { dd($product->id); }` in `CartController.php`

Answer (score 1):

Try to retrieve the associate model product

simply

```
Return $product
```

if not showing, that's means the cart model not save the session data, because the product data didnt retrieve
or using Request $requst its much easier